# WPF DataTrigger binding if parent is typeof

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a global scrollbar style for my application but I want the scrollbars to appear slightly different if they appear anywhere inside a specific type of control that has its IsActive property set to true. The code below works but I get a binding error every time the scrollbars aren't hosted in the custom control. Is there a way to check the ancestory before trying to set the trigger?

```cs
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=docking:DockingWindow}, Path=IsActive}"  Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource Gray130}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Are you sure, you want to go with that? I would suggest to let binding fail otherwise it will be performance hit that you will travel up the visual tree till you reach MainWindow. If you just need to check just immediate parent then it makes sense but not otherwise.

Comment: Instead of checking the ancestor, you can provide a `FallbackValue` which will be used when binding fails instead of throwing error.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I only get a binding warning and I think I can live with that. FallbackValue doesn't help with the warning does it? Any way to suppress the warning?